# How to use sshfs on Apple Silicon (M1)

Tags: macos, filesystem, apple-silicon

I'm trying to get sshfs working on Apple Silicon (M1) and Big Sur.

I have hit a brick wall. I installed some version of macFUSE already. I also tried building what I think is the latest for January 2021 but the instructions on https://github.com/osxfuse/osxfuse/issues/751 it sounds like it should already be possible, but I'm unable to get it working.

Anyone have a step-by-step out there to build, patch or install sshfs on Big Sur for M1?

Comment: Please include information about why you're not able to get it working. I.e. you are probably getting some kind of error message when building.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As of MacFuse 4.0.5, you need to

1. reboot info recovery mode and go to the terminal
2. disable SIP with `csrutil`
3. reboot
4. install macfuse
5. link the extension
6. reboot into recovery mode and re-enable SIP

[related details here](https://github.com/osxfuse/osxfuse/issues/741)