# API for user-space systems?

Tags: macos, filesystem, kernel-extensions

With Apple in the process of discouraging the use of kernel extensions, I am unsure what options they are now offering for people wanting to create access to a specific file system.

In the past there was MacFuse and MacFusion, but with the current road map this would likely rule this out as a solution, hence curious how we should approach something like [sshfs on Monterey instead of Big Sur](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/412096/5472)?

Comment: There are two problems with this question. 1) Code level questions - like what a specific API does or how to use them - are off topic here 2) There might be a practical question here, but we would need you to edit clarifying details here to include the specific file system you are trying to use on a specific macOS version and perhaps what research you did and why that research isn’t [a good answer](https://www.paragon-software.com/about/news/) for your problem. If my edits didn’t work, please refine with more details as needed…

Comment: BTW which StackExchange section would be best for this? My main research was trying to use Google, and not finding any solutions where a third-party FS was not done as a a kext or via MacFusion.

Comment: Hard to say. “This” needs some clarification if the current answer isn’t exactly what you sought. My advice is always to document your research. Show what exactly you searched in google and write a line or two why the top couple hits (reference which links you researched) and why they didn’t solve your issue. In that process it usually becomes clear to everyone where you’re stuck.

Answer (score 2):

MacFuse and the likes have not been "ruled out" - they continue to work just fine on the latest macOS versions.

Apple has released a [list](https://developer.apple.com/support/kernel-extensions/) of KPIs (kernel programming interfaces) that are deprecated now. This concerns mainly network and USB related interfaces. It does not concern the VFS KPIs that file systems use.

In future releases, it is likely given the direction that macOS has been taking, that VFS KPIs will also be deprecated on at least Apple Silicon machines. At that time, Apple will likely publicise alternatives - or remove the functionality. But that hasn't happened yet, and no-one can know how that will work out.

The only newer API in this area is the [NSFileProviderReplicatedExtension](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/fileprovider/nsfileproviderreplicatedextension?language=objc), but it is mostly aimed at cloud file systems such as DropBox, Google Drive and the likes.

Should Apple decide to completely remove support for third party file systems inside the kernel without providing a user-space alternative (which it is not evident that they will) - then you can always implement your file system in user-space and interface it as a network file system.